# FOP not wrapping properly on forward-slashes

Tags: java, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I'm using 2.3 of org.apache.xmlgraphics FOP to generate a table.
One of the columns of the table contains a compound identifier containing four parts separated by a forward slash

Note: I was also getting the same issue with 1.1 of FOP, but I've tried upgrading.

Using the following snippet I get a pdf (image below) where in the one row with the identifier "100000000006 / / 32143214321 / DFSG" the second forward slash is not displayed. I can select the text and all the forward slashes are present.

What is my formatting mistake?

Note: If I use an identifier with text between all spaces, eg. "100000000006 / 1 / 32143214321 / DFSG" all text displays as expected.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <fo:root>
      <fo:layout-master-set>
        <fo:simple-page-master master-name="spm1" page-height="595.45pt" page-width="792.0pt">
          <fo:region-body column-count="1" margin-bottom="57.6pt" margin-left="45.0pt" margin-right="45.0pt" margin-top="60pt" region-name="region-body"/>
          <fo:region-start extent="80pt" reference-orientation="90" region-name="regstart"/>
          <fo:region-end extent="80pt" reference-orientation="270" region-name="regend"/>
        </fo:simple-page-master>
      </fo:layout-master-set>
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="spm1">
        <fo:static-content flow-name="regstart">
          <fo:block/>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:static-content flow-name="regend">
          <fo:block/>
        </fo:static-content>
        <fo:flow flow-name="region-body">
          <fo:block background-color="white" color="black" font-family="Times New Roman, Times" font-size="12.0pt" font-style="normal" font-variant="normal"
                    font-weight="normal" orphans="2" text-align="start" text-decoration="none" text-indent="0pt" vertical-align="baseline" widows="2">

            <fo:block hyphenate="true" font-family="Arial, Helvetica" font-size="8pt">
              <fo:leader line-height="10pt"/>
            </fo:block>
            <fo:table>
              <fo:table-column column-width="65pt"/>
              <fo:table-column/>

              <fo:table-header>
                <fo:table-row height="14.4pt">
                  <fo:table-cell background-color="#CEDBF4" border-color="#FFFFFF" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" display-align="center"
                                 padding-left="5.4pt" padding-right="5.4pt">
                    <fo:block hyphenate="true" color="#000000" font-family="Arial, Helvetica" font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold" keep-with-next="always">
                      patient
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell background-color="#CEDBF4" border-color="#FFFFFF" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" display-align="center"
                                 padding-left="5.4pt" padding-right="5.4pt">
                    <fo:block hyphenate="true" color="#000000" font-family="Arial, Helvetica" font-size="8pt" font-weight="bold" keep-with-next="always">
                      total Fee Value
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
              </fo:table-header>
              <fo:table-body>
                <fo:table-row height="14.4pt">
                  <fo:table-cell background-color="#E7EDFD" border-color="#FFFFFF" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" display-align="center"
                                 padding-left="5.4pt" padding-right="5.4pt">
                    <fo:block hyphenate="true" color="#000000" font-family="Arial, Helvetica" font-size="8pt">
                      100000000006 / / 32143214321 / DFSG
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell background-color="#E7EDFD" border-color="#FFFFFF" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" display-align="center"
                                 padding-left="5.4pt" padding-right="5.4pt">
                    <fo:block text-align="right" hyphenate="true" color="#000000" font-family="Arial, Helvetica" font-size="8pt">
                      100.00&#160;UK Pound
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
                <fo:table-row height="14.4pt">
                  <fo:table-cell background-color="#E7EDFD" border-color="#FFFFFF" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" display-align="center"
                                 padding-left="5.4pt" padding-right="5.4pt">
                    <fo:block hyphenate="true" color="#000000" font-family="Arial, Helvetica" font-size="8pt">
                      100000000006 / 1 / 32143214321 / DFSG
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                  <fo:table-cell background-color="#E7EDFD" border-color="#FFFFFF" border-style="solid" border-width="0.25pt" display-align="center"
                                 padding-left="5.4pt" padding-right="5.4pt">
                    <fo:block text-align="right" hyphenate="true" color="#000000" font-family="Arial, Helvetica" font-size="8pt">
                      100.00&#160;UK Pound
                    </fo:block>
                  </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
              </fo:table-body>
            </fo:table>

          </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
      </fo:page-sequence>
    </fo:root>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[image]

Comment: I've found a site http://www.utilities-online.info/foprender where I can experiment with this and by removing the colors I can see that the text is definitely there

Comment: Taking a hint from other stackoverflow FOP answers I have found that adding a zero width space &#8203; after each slash results in the second slash moving down to a new line - which is good enough for my use case. It seems odd in this case as usually you do that to force long text to wrap, but in this case it is forcing a single character to wrap. This still does not feel quite right, but it works.

Comment: It sounds like the forward slash may not be recognized as a word boundary (ie a character where a word wrap is allowed), this could be either an issue in the font or an issue in FOP.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe in `<fo:table-column column-width="65pt"/>` the 65pt is not width enough?

Comment: Thanks. I did try that, but then I get issues with other instances of the identifiers

Comment: But if you make it (just for testing) 300 or 400 points width is then the second slash visible?

Comment: The code above is a subset of a much larger file with 11 columns, so widening the column means I steal space for one column then the other columns lose space. This is why I need the wrapping to trigger - as I put in a comment to the question I can do this using zero width spaces - so that is what I will go with for now.